# Is this a bad use of django class based views?

Tags: python, django

sometimes I have a hard time seeing if I am doing something the right way or not. Here is how I am using class based views in a project of mine.

```
class View(View):

    def get(self, request):

        if request.GET.get('something'):
            ...do something

        elif request.GET.get('bar'):
            ...do something

    def post(self, request):

        if request.POST.get('foo'):
            ...do something

        elif request.POST.get('bar'):
            ...do something
```

Is this django-like?

I have a lot of these in one view, and I came on a situation where the post may be getting nothing in return so I was unsure about how to catch it. What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use POST to send a form, you don't need to validate every single field in your view, you can do this in your form class. Check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation).

Comment: ahh ok, so I can make a form method that processes the data and then just call it in the view? is that what you are getting at?

Comment: Yes, you can create a Form class and use it to validate your data, you will just call `Form.is_valid()` method and all magic will happen.

Comment: ok thanks, useful to know for the future. My main point of the question though was to get around the use of the conditional statements in the post (each one will return the user to a different place) Does this help me do that?

Comment: You could use a [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) and override the [`get_success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) method.

Comment: one question I have about this that isn't in the docs...I send a form with context in get, I get the data in post. How do I call the form method with the data that I got in post? Surely I have to initialize it somehow, right? There is no example of what to do in the views in the docs

Comment: If you use a FormView you will define a `form_class` attribute in your view-class and use it. But if you need to use a generic View you can still create your own [`FormClass`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms), import it to your views file and instantiate as any other class with your `request.POST` data.

Answer (score 1):

To handle POST data, you should rather use a [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) or even a "model edit" view such as [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) or [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview).

Comment: So what you are saying is that my get method should have many different conditions, but they should each be posting to a different kind of view (whatever is appropriate)?